# Spring integration FTP

Tags: spring

На FTP сервер нужно выложить файлы, проблема в том что пути нужно строить динамически.Как это сделать?

```
@Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendSystemOutChannel")
  public MessageHandler messageHandler() {
    FtpMessageHandler messageHandler = new FtpMessageHandler(ftpOutboundSessionFactory());
    ExpressionParser EXPRESSION_PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();
    messageHandler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression("headers['file_name']"));
    messageHandler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    messageHandler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> {
      if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
        return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
      }
    });
    return messageHandler;
  }
```

Comment: Что означает динамически, можете привести пример? Можете показать что вы уже сделали?

Comment: Динамически -  это значит, что пути до каталогов  на FTP сервере должны строиться исходя из название файла. Пример 123456_test_20191212_123456777777.pdf. На сервере это будет 12/34/56/123456777777/test/20191212/123456_test_20191212_123456777777.pdf @Vlad Mamaev